# Scala: "In-place" the trait Inheriting without "new" keyword

Tags: scala

I can't understand why a syntax error occurs in this code:

*"T.scala" file*:

```
trait T
```

*"A.scala" file*:

```
class A

object A {
  def apply() = new A()
}
```

*"other.scala" file*:

```
val a = new A() with T  // ok
val b = A() with T  // syntax error ';' or newline expected
```

Can I create a new class instance with inheriting without using the `new` keyword?

I've not found anything about it.

Comment: You needn't split the code into a few files. All parts will live happily in the same source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A()` translates to `A.apply()` which is a method that returns a new object and is not the same as `new A()`.

You are essentially trying to do this (which will not work):

```
val b = A.apply()
val c = b with T
```

You can't use `with` on an object that has already been created.